# php parsing an array of PDO objects and converting it to json

Tags: php, arrays, json, pdo

I am fetching data from my mysql table using the pdo fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) statement. This returns an array of objects. This is the result when I var_dump the result:

```
array(3) {
[0]=>
 object(stdClass)#5 (7) {
 ["unique_user_id"]=>
 string(5) "11535"
 ["first_name"]=>
 string(5) "James"
 ["middle_name"]=>
 string(3) "Was"
 ["last_name"]=>
 string(2) "27"
 ["date_of_birth"]=>
 string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
 ["age"]=>
 string(1) "0"
 ["gender"]=>
 string(4) "Male"
}
[1]=>
object(stdClass)#8 (7) {
["unique_user_id"]=>
string(7) "1231209"
["first_name"]=>
string(5) "James"
["middle_name"]=>
string(5) "Maika"
["last_name"]=>
string(7) "Alfonso"
["date_of_birth"]=>
string(19) "1978-09-09 08:08:08"
["age"]=>
string(2) "21"
["gender"]=>
string(4) "Male"
}
[2]=>
object(stdClass)#9 (7) {
["unique_user_id"]=>
string(6) "332213"
["first_name"]=>
string(7) "Manfred"
["middle_name"]=>
string(7) "Kilonzo"
["last_name"]=>
string(6) "Kaloki"
["date_of_birth"]=>
string(19) "1998-09-09 07:09:07"
["age"]=>
string(2) "23"
["gender"]=>
string(4) "Male"
 }
}
```

How do I parse this and convert it to a php array. While I know that it would have been easier to just do the following:

```
$arr = $result->fetch; // returns an associative array
$json = array();
while ($row = $arr) {
            $json[] = array(                    
                'National ID'       => $row['unique_user_id'],
                'First Name'        =>  $row['first_name'],
                'Middle Name'       => $row['middle_name'],                     
                'Last Name'         => $row['last_name'],
                'DOB'               => $row['date_of_birth'],
                'Age'               => $row['age'],
                'Gender'            => $row['gender']
            ); // end of $json array
        }
        $json['success'] = true;
        echo json_encode($json);
```

I am, however, trying to adopt an object-oriented approach, thus fetching the data as object (fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)), rather than as an associative array (fetch()). Any ideas on how I could parse the array of objects so that I can convert it to php array and then encode it into json? Thank you

Comment: `json_encode` accepts objects as well as arrays, so there's no need to convert the object to an array in order to encode it to JSON.

Comment: thank you, works. Don't know why I was taking the longer way